# Correct n to use in calculating confidence interval of a proportion

Tags: confidence-interval

I know that my 95% confidence interval can be calculated for a proportion using:

$$
1.96 \times \sqrt{p(\frac{1-p}{n})}
$$

where $p$ is the proportion and $n$ is the number of trials.

But if my data is collected in a series of datasets (say, annual data collections), does this change my $n$? For example, if my data is framed:

| Year | TRUE | n |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2010 | 14 | 25 |
| 2011 | 17 | 25 |
| 2012 | 15 | 25 |
| 2013 | 11 | 25 |
| 2014 | 15 | 25 |

Do I calculate a total $p=\frac{14+17+15+11+15}{25\times5}=0.576$ and use:

1. $n=5$ because data was collected in five seperate experiments?
   $$
   1.96 \times \sqrt{0.576(\frac{1-0.576}{5})}
   $$
2. $n=125$ because data was collected on 125 events?
   $$
   1.96 \times \sqrt{0.576(\frac{1-0.576}{125})}
   $$

Furthermore, say there was an extra variable, $x$, for which I wanted to calculate a seperate proportion for ($\frac{\text{TRUE}}{x}$). Say $x$ represents the total number of job openings available and $n$ is the total applications, so $\frac{\text{TRUE}}{n}$ would be the job acceptance rate and $\frac{\text{TRUE}}{x}$ would be the positions filled rate:

| Year | TRUE | n | x |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2010 | 14 | 25 | 20 |
| 2011 | 17 | 25 | 20 |
| 2012 | 15 | 25 | 20 |
| 2013 | 11 | 25 | 20 |
| 2014 | 15 | 25 | 20 |

Would my $n$ for calculating my confidence interval for $\frac{\text{TRUE}}{x}$ still use the total from the $n$ column (either $5$ or $125$) or would it be the total from the $x$ column (either $5$ or $100$)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The model for this experiment is
$$
X_i \sim \mathrm{Bernoulli}(p)
$$
where the $X_i$ are the total outcomes of all of the trials.
If you had access to the whole data (ie, the outcomes of all 125 trials), your estimate of $p$ would be
$$
\hat{p} = \frac{1}{125} \sum_{i=1}^{215} X_i.
$$

Fortunately, you can compute this estimate from the data you do have, which id
$$
\frac{1}{125} \Bigl(
\sum_{i=1}^{25} X_i
+ \sum_{i=26}^{50} X_i
+ \dotsc
+ \sum_{i=101}^{125} X_i
\Bigr),
$$
where each of these sums are the total yearly outcomes that you have access to.

Now, by the central limit theorem, $\hat{p}$ has an approximate distribution of
$$
\hat{p} \stackrel{\mathrm{d}}{\approx}N\Bigl(p, \frac{p(1-p)}{\sqrt{125}}\Bigl),
$$
from which we have the standard error estimate
$$
\mathrm{se}(\hat{p})
= \frac{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})}{\sqrt{125}},
$$
and so the confidence interval
$$
\hat{p} \pm 1.96 \cdot \frac{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})}{\sqrt{125}}.
$$

The point here is that $n$ is the total number of independent trials, of which you have $125$.
If your data were the outcomes of the $125$ trials, you probably wouldn't be confused, and would confidently use $125$ as your $n$ value.

Well, it turns out that, even though you don't have access to the whole data, you still have all of the information that you need to compute this some $\hat{p}$, so the situation is the same!

Comment: Thank you so much! That answers the first question very well. Any insight to the additional question?